# Declaring a variable and schema in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

how to declare a variable in PIG? suppose i want to have a integer to have values as 10 how can i declare it in script? and how schema can be reused ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can use the 'Declare' command. It is used to describe one parameter and is used within the PIG script.

```
    %declare DESC 'Database'
    A = load 'data' as (name, desc);
    B = FILTER A by desc eq '$DESC';
    .....
```

You can get more about it here. [Pig Parameter](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/ParameterSubstitution)

Comment: There shouldn't have been a '$' before the DESC declaration. I fixed it, should work now.

Comment: It should start working in Pig version 0.14.0 according to  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2122